# Why call isChecked in RadioButton's onClick

Tags: android

Doesn't clicking a RadioButton imply that it was checked. There are code examples such as this:-

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_pirates:
            if (checked)
                // Pirates are the best
            break;
        case R.id.radio_ninjas:
            if (checked)
                // Ninjas rule
            break;
    }
}
```

One here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

Why can I not do just this instead:-

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_pirates:
            // Pirates are the best
            break;
        case R.id.radio_ninjas:
            // Ninjas rule
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [RadioButton documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html):

> A radio button is a two-states button that can be either checked or
>   unchecked. When the radio button is unchecked, the user can press or
>   click it to check it. However, contrary to a CheckBox, a radio button
>   cannot be unchecked by the user once checked.
>
> Radio buttons are normally used together in a RadioGroup. When several
>   radio buttons live inside a radio group, checking one radio button
>   unchecks all the others.
>
> See the [Radio Buttons guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html).

Hence, the primary purpose is to inform another radio button about the checking state.

And please be aware that `RadioButton` is inherited the `Button` behaviour. So, you can copy the same handling code for the Button plus the checked or unchecked state.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Doesn't that mean that pressing or clicking it will always check it? So why the isChecked()?